# Figure & Nr. when Sidecap is used in a scrreprt

Tags: sidecap

I use the `scrreprt` document class. I wanted to use the `sidecap` package for side caption.

As you can see here, since all the caption is after (right of) the "Figure & Nr:"  it takes away a lot of space.

[image]

I guess this is due because the way `scrreprt` document class makes figures. I would like to either have the second line of caption starting underneath the "Figure 2.3:" or to have the "Figure 2.3:" over the caption.

I hope you understand may problem. If you need a minimal working example just ask. Thanks

**Edit:**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{SCfigure}[50][h]
    \caption{\blindtext}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

The gap between the Figure and the caption (caused by the "Figure1.1:" is not really space efficient.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @samcarter I added one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `caption` package you can change the format of the side caption:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\captionsetup[SCfigure]{format=plain}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{SCfigure}[50][h]
    \caption{\blindtext}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @WitheShadow You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

With `scrreprt` you can also use environment `captionbeside` which is provided by the KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{captionbeside}{\setcapindent{0pt}}
\KOMAoptions{captions=outerbeside}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{figure}[hb]
  \begin{captionbeside}{\blindtext\label{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]